# Processing Formatted similar but nonuniform Excel with ForEachLoop

Tags: excel, file, ssis, foreach-loop-container, formatted

I am required to process multiple (32) formatted excel source files (they're actually .xlsm) that have embedded macros, functions, merged cells, etc.  These files started out the same, but got processed in many different countries and when they arrive, they look the same.  However, some numeric columns import as unicode and some import as float.  My problem is, I would prefer to write a package with a foreach loop container to process these files.  This works fine for some (the files that match), but I end up with about 12 - 15 files I have to process as separate packages (not within the foreach loop).  The rest of the files process fine because all the numeric fields match.

Does anyone know of a way to process these files without writing a separate package for each?

I'm using SQL Server Datatools 2010.

Thank you!

Mark

Comment: Preprocess each file by exporting to CSV?

Comment: I tried this, but there are some LARGE merged rows and columns that leave empty spaces.  Maybe I'll re-visit that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Excel is a fine data visualization tool. As a data transportation layer, it's gawdawful-horrible-very-bad-never-do-this-to-me-again.

Comment: I think all the green check marks on the SSIS screen is some sort of trigger mechanism to make us forget how difficult it is to make Excel play in the SSIS sandbox...